# sum of concave and convex function

Tags: functions, convex-analysis

Suppose $f$ is the sum of a concave and convex function, i.e. 
$$f=f_1+f_2$$
where $f_1$ is a concave function and $f_2$ is a convex function. I wonder if $f$ can be written as the following: 
$$f=\min\{g_1,g_2\}$$
for some concave function $g_1$ and convex function $g_2$.

I try to write the minimum as 
$$f_1+f_2=f=\min\{g_1,g_2\}=\frac{g_1+g_2-|g_1-g_2|}{2}$$
and express $g_1$ and $g_2$ in terms of $f_1$ and $f_2$. But it seems to me that it does not help much.

Comment: If you can do this to $f$, you can do this to any $C^2$ function (on an interval), as proved [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/13386/73324).

Comment: If $f=\min(g_1,g_2)$, then $g_1(x)\ge f(x)$ for all $x$. I'm pretty sure there is no concave $g_1(x)$ which lies above $f(x)=x^2$ everywhere.