# Is there an orthonormal basis for $L_2[0,1]$ consisting of convex functions?

Tags: real-analysis, hilbert-spaces, lp-spaces, orthonormal

Is there an orthonormal basis $\{\phi_{\alpha}\}$ for the space $L_2[0,1]$ of square-integrable functions from $[0,1]$ to $\mathbb{R}$ such that every $\phi_{\alpha}$ is convex?

Edit: A helpful question that is maybe easier: Can every square-integrable function: $[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ be written as a linear combination of convex functions? If not, then of course there is no hope. If so, then I think the next thing I'd check would be if Gram-Schmidt can preserve the convexity of functions....

Edit #2: If it is easier, how about for the space of *absolutely continuous* functions from $[0,1]$ to $\mathbb{R}$? (Or is this space no longer complete, so the question no longer makes sense?)

Comment: It looks like the linear combinations of convex functions are at least dense: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/13386/can-any-continuous-function-be-represented-as-a-sum-of-convex-and-concave-functi

Comment: Thanks! I think it's interesting even if we make some restrictions as mentioned in that question, like absolute continuity maybe.