# Optimization of competitive scenario

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

Suppose we have a function $f(x_1,x_2)$ with the following properties:

1. Let $x^*=\arg \max_{x_1} f(x_1,x_2=x^*)$ and $x^*=\arg \min_{x_2}f(x_1=x^*,x_2)$.
2. $f(x_1,x_2)$ is concave in $x_1$.
3. $f(x_1,x_2)$ is convex in $x_2$
4. $0 \le f(x_1,x_2) \le K$ non-negative and bounded
5. Assume the set of $(x_1,x_2)$ over which we are optimizing is compact.

Here are the thing I am trying to answer:

1. Is $(x_1,x_2)=(x^*,x^*)$ a saddle point?
2. Suppose I am trying to find the maximum of the following function
   \begin{align}
   g(x_1,x_2)=f(x_1,x_2)+f(x_2,x_1)  \text{ **note the flip**}
   \end{align} What can we say about maximum of $g$? Or anything else about $g$?
3. Does max (at least one) of $g$ occur at the point $x_1=x_2$?

Does anyone know of any similar scenarios or any materials on this so I can study them? I feel similar case should have been studied before. 
Thank you very much.

Comment: What does $x^*=\arg\max_{x_1}f(x_1,x_2=x^*)$ mean? Why does $x^*$ appear on the right-hand side of its definition?

Comment: what the above say is if we evaluate the $f$ at $x_2=x^*$ and then maximized with respect to $x_1$ then $x_1=x^*$ is maximizing?

Comment: Oh, I see, you're saying there exists a number $x^*$ such that $f(x_1,x^*)\le f(x^*,x^*)$ and $f(x^*,x_2)\ge f(x^*,x^*)$ for all $x_1$, $x_2$.

Comment: Yes. Should I edit my question? Is it unclear?

Answer (score 1):

1. If the concavity/convexity in (2, 3) are strict, then yes. From (1) it follows that $\partial f/\partial x_1=\partial f/\partial x_2=0$, so it is a critical point, but (2) and (3) together imply that it is neither a local maximum nor a local minimum.
2. All you can say is that $(x^*,x^*)$ is a critical point of $g$, but you don't know if it is a local maximum, a local minimum, or a saddle point. Examples of all three cases are provided by $f_1(x_1,x_2)=x_2^2-2x_1^2$, $f_2(x_1,x_2)=2x_2^2-x_1^2$, and $f_3(x_1,x_2)=x_2^2-x_1^2+x_1x_2$ respectively.
3. As above, $g$ could be convex, concave, or neither, so you can't guarantee whether a local maximum exists at all.

Comment: Can we say anything more about $g$ given this information or is it hopeless?

Comment: Well, the restriction of $g$ to the line $(x,x^*)$ is $x\mapsto f(x,x^*)+f(x^*,x)$, the sum of a convex function and a concave function. [This can be *any* twice-differentiable function](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/13386/856), so I'm not too hopeful that anything useful can be said.