# Write a function as sum of convex and concave functions

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives, convex-analysis

I'm trying to tackle a question for some time.
The question is:

> Let $f\in\mathcal{C}^2$ (i.e, $f$ is differentiable twice and $f',f''$ are continuous. Show that $f$ can be written as $f(x)=g(x)+h(x)$ where $g(x)$ is convex for any $x$ and $h(x)$ is concave for any $x$.

I proved it to the case that $f$ is defined on a closed domain $[-R,R]$. I couldn't show that it's true in the general case. I saw this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/13386/can-any-continuous-function-be-represented-as-a-sum-of-convex-and-concave-functi) (particularly, this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/13391/111334)),
but I always get to a dead end.

Please help me show that the statement is correct for and $f\in\mathcal{C}^2$.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Write $f''$ as the sum of a (not necessarily continuous) non-negative function and non-positive function.  Then integrate twice.

Comment: With $f'' = \max(f'', 0) + \min(f'', 0)$ you would even have a sum of *continuous* functions.

Comment: @MartinR, what if $f''(x)$ is not bounded? Gaffney, I don't understand what you mean...

Comment: @Galc127: I don't think that the boundedness of $f''$ is used here. But Gaffney wrote the answer, so he should explain it :)