# How many stationary points for this class of functions?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, optimization

Let $f,g \in C^{\infty}[a,b]$ such that $f(a) = g(a)$ and $f(b) = g(b)$ and $f',g' \leq 0$ and $f'' > 0$ and $g'' < 0$. By the Rolle theorem I can say that there's at least one stationary point for the function $h(x) = f(x) - g(x)$, I would be interested in state how many stationary points there are in $[a,b]$ for $h(x)$.

Is it possible to give a bound to such number of points?

The situation I'm trying to describe is something like:

[image]

Comment: If $f(x) = g(x) = -x$ then we do not have a stationary point for either $f$ or $g$. Is this what you meant? Could the question be worded more clearly?

Comment: I putted a picture that should be self explanatory of what I'm looking for. I tried to formalize that picture in general.

Answer (score 0):

First, there is at least one stationary point which, as you correctly state, comes from applying Rolle's Theorem to $h(x)$ on $[a,b]$ since 
  $$h(a) = h(b) = 0$$

Second, there is exactly one stationary point. We have
  $$f^{\prime\prime}(x) > 0, g^{\prime\prime}(x) < 0 \Rightarrow h^{\prime\prime}(x) = f^{\prime\prime}(x) - g^{\prime\prime}(x) > 0$$
which is to say that $h^{\prime}(x)$ is (strictly) increasing. Therefore we cannot have $h^{\prime}(x_{1}) = h^{\prime}(x_{2})$ for any distinct $x_{1},x_{2} \in [a,b]$ - in particular, if $h^{\prime}(x_{0}) = 0$ then 
  $$ x \neq x_{0} \Rightarrow h^{\prime}(x) \neq h^{\prime}(x_{0}) $$

Comment: I need to understand if my statement of the problem is correct as well that, I repeat, has been derived from a generalization of the graph I showed. Is such point the absolute max ?

Comment: Yes the graph appears to be an instance of your problem statement. Both functions are decreasing, intersect at two points and one is convex while the other is concave. The blue curve would be $f$ and the red curve $g$

Comment: Last question... assuming $f'',g''$ have the same sign does the statement hold as well?

Comment: No. If $f^{\prime\prime}, g^{\prime\prime} > 0$ then no conclusion can be made about the sign of $h^{\prime\prime}$ - it could be positive at some points and negative at others, meaning that $h$ can be sometimes increasing and sometimes decreasing. You could relax the conditions, through, by requiring that $f^{\prime\prime} > g^{\prime\prime}$ or $f^{\prime\prime} < g^{\prime\prime}$ - both would guarantee the monotonicity of $h^{\prime}$.

Comment: So sums of convex functions couldn't be convex? Is this the conclusion?

Comment: Differences. If $f^{\prime\prime}$ and $g^{\prime\prime}$ have the same sign then $f$ convex means $-g$ is concave, $h = f-g$ is the sum of a convex and a concave function. The sum of a convex function $f$ and a concave function $g$ may be non-convex. The sum of two convex functions is always convex, but $g$ convex means $-g$ is concave (or $g$ concave means $-g$ is convex)

Comment: Yes sorry, i mean't exactly your argument. However in the case of $f'',g''>0$ is it possible to give a bound on the number of stationary points?

Comment: No I don't think so. You might want to take a look at [this thread](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/13386/can-any-continuous-function-be-represented-as-a-sum-of-convex-and-concave-functi) to see that sums of convex and concave functions give a large variety of functions, some of which can have arbitrarily many stationary points. (I might be wrong here - you should write a new question if you want a better answer!)