# What does "a convex-$\bigcap$ continuation" mean?

Tags: functions, convex-analysis, coding-theory

I'm reading a paper named *The Context-Tree Weighting Method Basic Properties, 1995* and everyone can access to http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.14.352&rep=rep1&type=pdf for free.

I have a question about a math symbol in this paper. It is at the beginning of Part B of Chapter 6, page 5.

> Definition 8: Let $$\begin{eqnarray}\gamma(z)=
> \begin{cases}
> z, &0 \le z < 1 \cr \frac{1}{2}\log z + 1, & z \ge 1 \cr
> \end{cases}
> \end{eqnarray}$$ hence $\gamma(.)$ is a convex-$\bigcap$ continuation of $\frac{1}{2}\log z + 1$ for $0 \le z < 1$ satisfying $\gamma(0) = 0$.

Does anyone know what "a convex-$\bigcap$ continuation of" means? I never seen this in mathematics before.

Update:

Initially, I guess $\bigcap$ means the shape of $\gamma()$ coz if I draw it out in 2-D plane(X-Y), the shape of $\gamma$ will look like an upside-down bowl. But it is not a convex function. Besides, it is a little bit funny that a celebrated paper did use such an unprofessional symbol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard terminology is "convex vs concave", but there are [variations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concave_function) (indeed the names are [confusing](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/why-does-convex-function-mean-concave-up)). For example:

```
      convex        |     concave 
  convex downwards  |  convex upwards
    concave up      |    convex cap
```

The "cap" sign, in convex-$\bigcap$, points surely to the latest - and that terminology is [not too rare](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/87311/is-the-following-function-convex-cap-how-to-maximize-it) - and, granted, is the less ambiguous. It's what normally we call a concave function.

In your example, it's not strictly concave.

Comment: Let me confirm it: so my example wanna tells me it looks like a shape of $\cap$ that is convex cap and however, it is not strictly concave in math, right?